# MySQL Replication not working on binlog-do-db

Tags: mysql-replication, master-master

I set up `MySQL master-master replication` on my 2 Ubuntu VM. Configuration and connection done correctly according to [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_master_master_replication) guide.  Here is my problem.

1. I print the master status on master 1 and it gives position `XXX`, then I jump to Master 2 and print slave status it is also prints its position as `XXX`.
2. I change any configuration beside the must-replicated db position changes. (As usual)
3. Problem is this when I insert any record to must-replicated db position does not change. Also record does not replicated to Master 2 must-replicated DB.

In logs also it does not give any info about replication.

Here is my 1st master-slave configuration in `my.conf` files:

Master:

```
log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog-do-db=REPLICATE_DB
server-id=1
```

Slave:

```
server-id=2
master-host=10.1.1.171
master-user=slave_user
master-password=your_password
master-connect-retry=60
replicate-do-db=REPLICATE_DB
```

Comment: check on master 1 and master 2 the Slave_IO_Running & Slave_SQL_Running via slave status, make sure it's YES. if one of them  is NO, check your setup again.

Comment: these are both yes

Comment: have you try to recreate the db ?, is it sync ? if yes, try to insert records.

Comment: they are sync, when i insert records database just do nothing for replication. I cannot see any action on logs or database.

Comment: remove replicate-do-db and have you try using another option like replicate-wild-do-table=db_name.%  and  replicate-ignore-db ?